# Как разбить json на ключ-значение в php?

Tags: php, json

Есть такой ответ от сервера

```
{"response":{"count":2711,"items":[{"id":990847,"owner_id":-Айдишка группы,"title":"Название товара","description":"Описание","price":{"amount":"270000","currency":{"id":643,"name":"RUB"},"text":"Цена руб."},"category":{"id":902,"name":"Подборка","section":{"id":9,"name":"Категория"}},"date":1499116687,"thumb_photo":"Ссылка на картинку","availability":0}]}}
```

Нужно разбить по параметрам:

```
Название
Описание
Цена
Подборка
Категория
Ссылка на картинку
```

Comment: Это называется JSON вообще-то.

Answer (score 5):

```
$json = "{"response":{"count":2711,"items":[{"id":990847,"owner_id":-Айдишка группы,"title":"Название товара","description":"Описание","price":{"amount":"270000","currency":{"id":643,"name":"RUB"},"text":"Цена руб."},"category":{"id":902,"name":"Подборка","section":{"id":9,"name":"Категория"}},"date":1499116687,"thumb_photo":"Ссылка на картинку","availability":0}]}} ";

    $array = json_decode($json,true);
    print_r($array);
```

И так мы получили ассоциативный массив, и можем получить доступ к нужным вам элементам.

Comment: Задумался над тем, как правильно писать 'и так' в данном случае: слитно или раздельно. В итоге, решил, что правильнее рекомендовать  заменить на 'таким образом' ))))

Answer (score 3):

Функция `json_decode` вам поможет)))
[мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)